# Accessing Excel sheet using python in Raspbian

Tags: python

How to store data by sliding between various rows and columns of excel sheet using python? I have used file concept
(fout = open('filename.csv',"+a")
to open the excel file. I need to know how to access the rows and columns of this excel.

Comment: Hello and welcome. I am putting this on hold as it is not specific to the Pi but a general programming question. Try Stack Overflow but be aware of possible duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, a CSV file isn't an Excel file - you don't actually need to access it as excel, you can use the excellent, [included library CSVReader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).  Secondly, this isn't a Pi question, it's a python programming question.

But since you asked about Excel:

I typically use XLRD for this sort of thing.  Install it using

```
pip install xlrd
```

Then in python you can do something like:

```
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('filename.csv')
first_sheet = xlrd.sheet_by_index(0)
```

I typically also use [Martin's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33937236/python-xlrd-use-range) to access cell ranges, which looks like this (note that the cell format is R1C1 not the A1, B2 format you might be used to):

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(r"input.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

def get_cell_range(start_col, start_row, end_col, end_row):
    return [sheet.row_slice(row, start_colx=start_col, end_colx=end_col+1) for row in xrange(start_row, end_row+1)]

data = get_cell_range(0, 2, 3, 6)   # A3 to D7
print data
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. In csv file, I could able to write, but I want the files to be copied column wise , 
i.e once the number of entries reaches 5 (say 1,2,3,4,5), it should go to next column. How can I do this using python (I couldnt able to install xlrd, nor similar files, hence has only csv option). Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes, you would still be be able to do that in CSV reader, just use the index for the column that corresponds to the correct one you wanted - in your example, '7' would be row[3] using normal indexing - so you would just cycle through the rows picking out row[3], etc.

Comment: Can you help me with a code snippet for it? because I am pretty new to python and couldnt get hold of the logic you discuss. I am actually continuosly reading data from a source and storing it in a .csv file. If number of data entry reaches 5 it must move to next column

Comment: I'd have a look over on Stack Overflow as the mod suggests.  This is a very common type of question. :)